# rotating a slice figure and customized figure size for saving

Tags: matlab, slice, matlab-figure

I am struggling to rotate the second subplot in a way that ticks would be in the bottom of plot instead of on the top and the second question is how I can customize the size of figure when I will save it and it wouldn't shrink its size to the normal figure [image]

```
   col         = {'b.','m.','g.','r.','c.','k.'};
   col_context = {[0.1, 0.6, 0],[0.6, 0.1, 0]};
   MarkerSize = 24;
   
   cols = [0:1/32:1; 0:1/32:1; 0:1/32:1]';
   t     = 1:Nt;
   hAx(1) =subplot(2,1,1), bar(p,'k'),   hold on
   plot(q,'.c','MarkerSize',16), hold on
   plot(q,':c')
   for g = 1:Ng
       for i = 1:max(o(g,:))
            j = find(o(g,:) == i);
            plot(t(j),j - j + 3 + g,col{rem(i - 1,6)+ 1},'MarkerSize',MarkerSize)
       end
   end
   title('Final outcome, performance and reaction times')
   ylabel('Expected utility'), spm_axis tight, hold off, box off
   hAx(2) =subplot(2,1,2);
   
   colormap(linspecer); 
   hAx(2) = gca;
   set(gcf, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0, 0.01, 1, 0.99]);
   h = slice(Xc,[],[],1:T2) ;
   sliceAxis = get(h(1), 'Parent');
   
   set(hAx(2), 'DataAspectRatio', [1.5 2.3 1.3]);
   alpha(hAx(2), 0.85);

   
   set(hAx(2), 'YTick',linspace(1,4,4) , 'YTickLabel', {'none','small-reward','large-reward','shock',''});
   set(hAx(2), 'XTick',linspace(1,4,4) , 'XTickLabel', {'1st-TS','2nd-TS','3d-TS','4th-TS',''});
   zlim([0 T2])
   zlh=zlabel('Trials','FontSize',15);
  
   zlh.Position(2) = zlh.Position(2) - abs(zlh.Position(2) * 0.075);
   ylabel('Posterior of prior preferences');
   grid(hAx(2), 'on');
   view([-55 18]);
   camroll(270);
   
   
   cb = colorbar();
   set(cb,'position',[.025 .2 .015 .3])
   hold on;
   drawnow  
   sliceAxisPosition = get(sliceAxis, 'Position');
  
   title('Reward Values');
```

Comment: I often save the figure as an .svg file and edit the axes in a vector graphics editor because it is generally much easier to make things look nice there than messing around in matlab. Inkscape is a good open source vector graphics editor if you don't already have adobe illustrator.